# Creating a "Features" column from 5 other metrics with true/false data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that has 5 columns, with what I will "Features" - Vegan, Non GMO, Soy Free, Dairy Free, Gluten Free.

For each product entry, I have setup simple true/false data validation based on whether that product meets the metric.

[image: Sample of sheet data]

To the right, you can see a "Features" column. What I want to do is create a filter on that features column that will display products on a website based on whether any metric is meet, ie whether the product is vegan, non gmo etc

You can see what im trying to do over at [VitaminSpecs](https://vitaminspecs.com/). You can see the last filter currently returns "null" due to no data, but thats where I want to list "Vegan" "Non GMO" etc and allow customers to be able to multi-select those metrics

**Update:** From the formula provided by Player0, I am able to generate the following in the spreadsheet and on website

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEFue.png)
[Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taXOy.png)

Answer (score 0):

try in T2:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(O2:S=TRUE, O1:S1&",", )),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

Comment: When I had the formula the formula with TRUE, it was completely blank. I had customized the TRUE > YES and NO to a simple dash `=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(O2:S=YES, O1:S1&",", )),,9^9))), ",$", ))` It then returns 5 columns of NAME? to match the 5 metrics

Comment: @Netbuddy try: `=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(O2:S="YES", O1:S1&",", )),,9^9))), ",$", ))`

Comment: It now successfully shows the relevant features in the features column seperated by a comma, so thats perfect. It also shows those metrics in the features filter on the website, but it doesnt actually filter properly by those metrics and it also seems to break the other filters on the website pretty much completely. If I remove the "Features" filter and simply put up say, a "Dairy Free" filter, that shows Yes and dash, everything works. So Im thinking trying to combine these 5 metrics into one field might be a deal breaker.

Comment: Ive added a couple pictures of how the spreadsheet now looks and the website filter in the original question. If you play around with the filter a bit, you can see its broken atm.

Comment: @Netbuddy try in T2: `=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(  IF(O2:S2="YES", O1:S1&",", )),,9^9))), ",$", ))` and drag this formula down

Comment: The output in the sheet has shifted and the filter on the website reflects that, but it still seems to be broken. Thanks for all your help so far. Its proving to be a tough nut to crack. I have added more pics to the original post

Comment: If was to replace all the booleans (Yes, -) with simply Non GMO for the Non GMO vitamins, Gluten Free for Gluten Free vitamins, then how could I take those values and combine them in the "Features" column?